# ! LaTeX Error: File `chickenize.tex' not found

Tags: chickenize

I don't know what is wrong. I'm fairly sure I installed the package. Can someone who has installed the `chickenize` package test this?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Madrid}        % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default}  % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}   % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
}
\setbeamertemplate{theorems}[numbered]
\usepackage[algosection,ruled,lined,linesnumbered,longend]{algorithm2e}

\usepackage{fontspec,chickenize,xcolor}

\directlua{luatexbase.add_to_callback("post_linebreak_filter",randomchars,"chickenize")}

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\title[ShortTitle]{LongTitle}
\subtitle{Subtitle}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{\today}
\titlegraphic{\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{nyu_shanghai}}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}{Outline}
  \tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Works if I substitute `example-image` for `nyu-shanghai`, since I don’t have your image

Comment: By the way, you shouldn’t use `fontenc` with luatex.  Just write your file in utf-8; T1 is very limited.

Comment: @Thérèse  still doesn't work even if I get rid of fontenc  btw I am missing a chickenize.tex   instead only have chickenize.sty file

Comment: It is an error in the miktex package installation. It seems to have forgotten to install chickenize.tex. I will report it.

Comment: I added an issue https://github.com/MiKTeX/miktex-packaging/issues/171. It should be resolved soon. In the meantime you can get the missing file from ctan.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  I added the file, but it still gives me this error.

Comment: Where did you add it? The best would be to put it in your document folder for now.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer  In the MiKTeX package folder

Comment: as I said: use your document folder. miktex will update the package in a few days and then you can remove it again.